# Sums of sparse matrices modulo 2

Tags: matrix, cuda, opencl

I have a set of sparse matrices modulo 2 (i.e systems of equations in the format "a XOR b XOR ... XOR c = 0 or 1" compressed by me into reduced row echelon form).

This is a rather large set (1 million matrices).

Some of them interact with each other. For example if a matrix contains the row "a XOR b = 0" and another "a XOR b = 1", then those 2 matrices are in conflict. More generally, conflicts are found by calculating the sum of the two matrices.

The goal is to find all the conflicts. This can be a distributed task because the sum of each pair independent. Right now, I do this on CPU with 24 threads who check all the relevant pairs one by one. This can take a while if there are 1 million x 1 million interactions for example.

How can I achieve this faster (i.e on GPU or in the cloud, using Cuda/OpenCL/Vulkan) ?

Comment: Well, you have $10^{12}$ tasks to work through. There is nothing you can do about the number, so you must make each task fast. Show us the code you're using, and perhaps we can help.